# Не могу подключить proxy к jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, proxy

Суть задачи распарсить страницу, вытащить список доменов, каждый из них проверить через jsoup(или нет?) на site:xdomain.com , дабы узнать количество страниц.Пробовал так:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "195.178.146.166");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3133");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "195.178.146.166");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "3133");
```

ещё нашёл такие примеры:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(
                Proxy.Type.HTTP,
                InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("127.0.0.1", 8080)
              );
Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect(request)
                .proxy(proxy)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)")
                .timeout(5000).get();
```

В итоге результат никакой,со второго исполнения кода запрос перестаёт возвращать количество страниц. Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: а у вас proxy локально стоит?

Comment: А прокси авторизацию не требует?

Comment: Нет, не локально, просто для проверки брал адреса с портами из интернетов. Ни один из вышеописанных вариантов не помог.

Comment: Кстати как альтернативу пытался сделать один запрос по принципу:
'String request = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + query + "&num=20";' , где query = "site:domain1.com OR site:domain2.com" , к сожалению при наличии более двух доменов респонс идёт странный от гугла, никак не разберусь...

Comment: @ФёдорТеслюк а попробуйте выполнить запрос curl. Сработает?

Comment: ' URLConnection connection = new URL("https://www.google.com/search?q=site:domain1.com OR site:domain2.com OR site:domain3.com&num=20").openConnection();' Вы об этом методе? Если да, то: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL.

Comment: Сейчас при небольшом количестве запрашиваемых(в цикле) доменов всё отрабатывает, но при большом количестве обращений гугл прекращает отвечать с :Service is not available, по этому либо прокси(никак не могу заставить обращаться через него),либо группировать всё одним запросом,что так же пока не принесло результата...

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете указать proxy-сервер напрямую, без создания отдельного объекта.

```
Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect(request)
                .proxy("<имя хоста>", <номер порта>)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)")
                .timeout(5000).get();
```

Comment: Это замечательно, спасибо, но толку от этого нет...

Answer (score 0):

```
   **Подключение proxy к Jsoup**


    URL url = new URL("http://");

    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("00.00.00.00", 8080));
    HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);

    uc.connect();

    String line = null;
    StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        tmp.append(line);
    }

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(String.valueOf(tmp));
```