# Реально ли в Jsoup подсунуть "левый" IP адрес?

Tags: java, взлом

Стоит ли вообще копать в эту сторону? На сайте защита-скриннинг, не позволяющая часто подключаться к серверам, временно блокируется доступ. Пробовал подсовывать разные юзер-агенты, но видимо все же банят по IP. Что можно сделать?

Comment: Лолчто. Для смены IP адреса используй прокси

Comment: Я ничего не смог найти.

Comment: Прокси. Я нашел что-то связанное с подключением и указанием ip сервера. Это не то (?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599933/how-to-use-an-http-proxy-in-java

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657601/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-proxy-%D0%BA-jsoup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для запроса с другого IP-адреса можно использовать прокси-сервер.

```
Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect(request)
                .proxy("<имя хоста прокси>", <номер порта прокси>)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)")
                .timeout(5000).get();
```

Comment: Тоесть я могу указывать рандомные айпи? :)

Comment: @Flippy Вообще-то хосты не с каждым ip доступны в сети и прокси-сервер не на каждом хосте запущен.

Comment: @Flippy список прокси нужно нагуглить.